How to deal with Bias Gradient Matrix for biased CRB(Cramér–Rao bound) calculation if the gradient matrix is m-by-n but $m \neq n$?
I am doing a model for collabrative localization and using the CRB(Cramér–Rao bound) as the localization performance measurement. I want to consider interference caused by NLOS and clutter, therefore the received radar echoes becomes biased. The biased calculation used is from Rethinking Biased Estimation: Improving Maximum Likelihood and the Cramér–Rao Bound, that is
$E\{||\hat{\theta} - E\{\hat{\theta}\}||^2\} \geq Tr((I + D({\theta_0}))J^{-1}(\theta_0)(I + D({\theta_0})^T)$
,where $\hat{\theta}$ is the arbitrary estimator of $\theta_0$, $I$ is the identity matrix, $J$ is the Fisher information matrix of $\theta_0$, and $D({\theta_0}) = \frac{db(\theta_0)}{d\theta_0}$ is the bias gradient.
My problem is, in my model, what I want to find is the localization error of position by CRB. The observation is the time delay, so that the biased error value can be expressed as $\tau_e = 2\frac{\sqrt{(x_e - x)^2+(y_e - y)^2}}{c}$, where $(x_e,y_e)$ is the position of an assumption clutter and $(x,y)$ is the position of target. Assuming that the biased delay is caused by the target reflected to clutter and then reflected back.
As a result, for a MIMO bistatic radar with M-Tx and N-Rx for a single target and single clutter, $\tau_e$ would be a 1xMN matrix $[\tau_{e_{11}},\tau_{e_{12}},...,\tau_{e_{1N}},...,\tau_{e_{MN}}]$. To calculate the bias gradient, $D(x,y) = \frac{d \tau_{e}}{d (x,y)}$ would be a 2xMN matrix that could not be added to an identity matrix as shown in the biased CRB algorithm above. So I am wondering how to deal with it if the gradient martix does not have the same size for column and raw, or maybe my understanding of the biased CRB algorithm is incorrect?
Thank you!
